# From axiom of regularity, how can I prove $x \notin y \lor y \notin x$

Tags: set-theory

From axiom of regularity, how can I prove following statement? $$x \notin y \lor y \notin x$$

I’ve been reading about ZF theory.  So far, I understood the axiom of regularity as follows:

$$\forall x (x \neq \phi \Rightarrow  \exists z. z \in x \land z \cap x = \phi)$$

From this, (and with other axioms in ZF), I should be able to derive the first statement, but have not managed to do so.

Question:

- How can I derive the statement within ZF?

Comment: The axiom of regularity says that every nonempty set is disjoint from one of its elements. Apply that to the set $\{x,y\}.$

Comment: Note that your axiom of regularity is not the usual one, where $z$ is required to be an element of $x$.

Comment: Your axiom of regularity always holds if we put $z=\emptyset$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan You are right.. I mis copied.  Fixed the axiom.

Comment: You haven't fixed it.  His point is that you need $z$ to be a member of $x$.  $\forall x \left( x \neq \emptyset \implies \exists z\in x (z \cap x = \emptyset) \right).$

Comment: Again mistaken, so fixed again..

Comment: Some authors call it Foundation instead of Regularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axiom of regularity states that:

$$\forall x(x\neq \emptyset\rightarrow \exists y(y \in x \wedge y\cap x=\emptyset))$$

Now let $a, b$ be given. Consider $x=\{a, b\}$. By the axiom of regularity, there exists $y \in \{a, b\}$ such that $y\cap \{a, b\}=\emptyset$. Since $y \in \{a, b\}$, either $y=a$ or $y=b$. If $y=a$, then $y\cap \{a, b\}=\emptyset$, so $b \notin y=a$. If $y=b$, then $y\cap \{a, b\}=\emptyset$, so $a\notin y=b$.

Comment: To the proposer: Similarly, in ZF we cannot have $x\in y\in z\in x:$ By the Pairing Axiom $\{x,y\}$ and $\{y,z\}$ exist. By the Pairing Axiom again, $\{\{x,y\}.\{y,z\}\}$ exists. By the Union Axiom, $\bigcup  \{\{x,y\},\{y,z\}\}=\{x,y,z\}$ exists. If $x\in y\in z\in x$ then $\{x,y,z\}$ violates Regularity.